# Which one is faster and better? Is this compare method true?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

I am working on STM8S microcontroller with IAR compiler.

I try to compare versions of `d.M0.bit._5=d.M1.bit._7;` and I write   cycle    and code memory differences as a command below.

```
typedef union 
{
 struct
 {
  unsigned char _0 :1;
  unsigned char _1 :1;
  unsigned char _2 :1;
  unsigned char _3 :1;
  unsigned char _4 :1;
  unsigned char _5 :1;
  unsigned char _6 :1;
  unsigned char _7 :1;
 } bit;
unsigned char data;
} m;

typedef struct 
{

  m M0,
    M1,
    M2,
    } dm_;

#pragma location = 0x050 
dm_ d;

// original version;

 d.M0.bit._5=d.M1.bit._7;   // 21 byte(difference from total code memory),
                            // 18 cycle (PC:Programme Counter)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------   
// second version;

    d.M0.bit._5=0;          // 18 byte(difference from total code memory), 
   if(d.M1.bit._7)          // 15 cycle (PC:Programme Counter)
    d.M0.bit._5=1;

// third version;
    d.M0.data &=~(1<<5);    // 18 byte(difference from total code memory), 
   if(d.M1.data & 0x80)     // 15 cycle (PC:Programme Counter)
    d.M0.data |=(1<<5);
```

It seems so, second and third version is equal and more efficient than original version but I don't know is this a confidental compare?

In debugger mode, I count PC cycle number and compile all code to check differences each code memory and new code memory.

In addition, it could be not important but assembly coverage of `d.M0.bit._5=d.M1.bit._7;` version of code has more assembly instruction.

Comment: Also benchmark non-bitfield solutions.  Bit fields are *highly* non-portable - every compiler is free to implement them almost entirely as they please - ordering within the underlying data and ordering of the bits themselves are not specified.  By using them, you are all too likely locking yourself into a specific compiler and maybe even platform depending on what your code needs to do.  You probably don't want to be locked-in like that.

Comment: What do you mean by "confidental"? "Confidential" (that is, "secret") doesn't seem to fit here. Did you mean something like "correct", "reliable"?

Comment: What optimizations were enabled?

Comment: @ Fabio Turati I mean that " is this compare method reliable."

Comment: @ Lundin in IAR Workbech Compiler Optimization setting, high level optimization was activated. ( Enabled transformations : Common subexpression elimination, Loop unrolling, Function inlining, Code motion, Type-based alias analysis and Cross call )

Comment: Well, it seems that the compiler possibly decided to do the first one as a 16 bit copy? You'll have to disassemble the code to see what you actually ended up with. The latter versions seem to be translated to bit set/clear and bit checks as they should (assuming STM8 supports such, I don't know that ones asm).

Comment: Note: both the `if` versions ( `if(d.M1.bit._7) ` and `if(d.M1.data & 0x80)` will cause conditional jumps to be generated. Which will cause two code paths with different numbers of cycles(a pipelined architecture like x86 could suffer from the invalidated jump). Also, on some architectures (I don't know the STM8S ), the shift operations can take different amount of clocks, depending on the shift count.

Comment: @ Lundin, yes, latters versions disassemble code is simple like bit set/clear but disassemble code of original version uses an 8 bit Accumulator but I think, like your guess, it is shifting 8 bit register two times so it is possible using as 16 bit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: C was designed in the spirit of exploiting the features of the platform as effectively as possible. With embedded systems, fighting for portability is a nonsense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then use bit masks and fixed-width variables - *so you know where each bit is*.  If you want to "exploit... the features of the platform" do it in ways that are predictable and controllable.  Note the comment about:  "Well, it seems that the compiler possibly decided to do the first one as a 16 bit copy? You'll have to disassemble the code to see what you actually ended up with." How is *that* morass preferable to something like `uint8_t` and bit masks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, it is better to avoid ifs, since unless you have a conditional move instruction, if == branch == slow.

The shortest known formula to assign bits from one value to another is:

```
r = a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask)
```

Here is the source for the formula: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#MaskedMerge

So the final result in your case would be:

```
unsigned char a = d.M0.data;
unsigned char b = (d.M1.data >> 2); // put bit 7 into 5th position
unsigned char mask = 0x20; // will assign to a the 5th bit of b
d.M0.data = a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask);
```

On my Intel i5 it is about 6-13% faster than the other options. I expect the difference will be more prominent on slower CPUs.

But it is a bit tricky, so it is up to you if the speed gain worth the code readability...

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                       Time           CPU Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------------
bits_assign                   212 ns        212 ns    3288700
bits_assign_if_bit            212 ns        210 ns    3327297
bits_assign_if_data           203 ns        203 ns    3457701
bits_assign_branchless        188 ns        188 ns    3713355
```